# My Killswitch is not working in Discord.py and it's not working, no error message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit

So, I have been working on a killswitch for my bot in discord.py, and I've hit a stump. My kill switch is not working and it's not giving me an error. If anyone can help I would very much appreciate it.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import asyncio
import random
import json
import random
import discord.utils
from datetime import datetime
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',')

client.remove_command('help')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
     global startdate
     startdate = datetime.now()
     await client.change_presence(
       status=discord.Status.online,
       activity=discord.Game('Type "," to activate me! e'))
     print('Bot is ready.')

@client.command(aliases=["shut", "shutdown", "quit", "stop_that", "stahp", "kill"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def stop(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
 embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Green())
 embed.add_field(name="I have been Killed", value=f"{member.name} has killed me! That's very unpog of them!", inline=False)
 embed.set_image(url="")
 embed.set_thumbnail(url="")
 embed.set_footer(text=f"Killed By: {ctx.author.name}")
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 await client.logout()

client.run('no token for you :)')
```

Comment: have you tried out client.close()?

Comment: Is your intention to run the command simply as `,shut`, or `,shut some_user`?

Comment: Thanks you guys for the support! you've helped me make the kill switch look nicer

Answer (score -2):

The first thing I saw in your code was when you defined the embed you only defined the color. I went ahead and added the other fields for title and description and set them to None

The second issue I saw was that when adding the field value, you called `member.name`
however you were supposed to call `member.display_name`

The final two issues are you were defining an embed image and thumbnail, however you did not pass any values. Instead, either pass `None` or do not define them in the first place

`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import asyncio
import random
import json
import random
import discord.utils
from datetime import datetime
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',')

client.remove_command('help')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global startdate
    startdate = datetime.now()
    await client.change_presence(
      status=discord.Status.online,
      activity=discord.Game('Type "," to activate me! e'))
    print('Bot is ready.')

@client.command(aliases=["shut", "shutdown", "quit", "stop_that", "stahp", "kill"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def stop(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=None, description=None, color=0x00FF00)
    embed.add_field(name="I have been Killed", value=f"{member.display_name} has killed me! That's very unpog of them!", inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Killed By: {ctx.author.name}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await client.logout()

client.run('YOUR TOKEN HERE')
```

`

Comment: There's no need to initialize embed fields as None, they're empty by default if you don't give them a value. `member.name` isn't wrong either - `display_name` is something else, `name` exists as well.